# [Custom ScrollView can not scroll

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a `CustomScrollView` that extends `ScrollView`,then I do something in the method `OnDraw()`. unfortunately, the `CustomScrollView` can not scroll anymore, here is the code what i do.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Log.d(null,"current measured height is:"+getMeasuredHeight());
    Log.d(null,"screen height is:"+mScreenHeight);

    Rect rect=new Rect(50,0,mScreenWidth-50,mScreenHeight<<1);
    canvas.drawRect(rect,mFilledPaint);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec,int heightMeasureSpec){
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec,heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension((int)mScreenWidth,(int)mScreenHeight<<1);
}

private void init(){
    mFilledPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mFilledPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    mScreenWidth=((Activity)mContext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    mScreenHeight=((Activity)mContext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing these codes in a custom `View` (just let your class extends `View`) and add it to a `ScrollView`. overriding `ScrollView` methods will disable its default behaviors like scrolling.

Comment: Thanks,but I don't think that would be the best solution.What I want to draw in the CustomScrollView would be many irregular rectangles.I'm  suck in english,could you understood what I want to explain?

Comment: What do you mean by "irregular rectangles"? can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Just like the Pinterest and the Google Play,I want to add pictures in the ScrollView programmatically.Here is the effect[link](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-YhBXiBBR354/T_LI3WK7BZI/AAAAAAAAAAY/LI4dyHaVa3M/s739/%E6%9C%AA%E5%91%BD%E5%90%8D.jpg) what I realized.

Comment: as I said, you can do the drawing job in `onDraw()` method of a custom view, and then add it to a normal `ScrollView`. but, in some cases you can easily use `ListView` which you can see the tutorial here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Remove onMeasure overriding if you just need to paint something extra.

Comment: I tried remove onMearsure overriding then nothing will be drawn in the CustomScrollView even though proterty android:fillViewport="true" been set.

Comment: I remove onMearsure overriding and set the height android:layout_height="fill_parent",but the CustomScrollView still can not scroll.

Comment: stupid question, but do you have enough content inside the ScrollView that it should scroll ?

Comment: Is there any solution can make the `CustomScrollView` scroll only drawing pictures?